# How can I keep TempData when browser refresh but null if user leave the page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Is there anyways to keep TempDate if browser or page refresh but null or reset if user leaves to another page then go back.

I am able to Keep TempData using TempData.Keep() but I want to reset it if user go to another page and come back.

```
var projectId= TempData["projectId"];
    TempData.Keep("projectId");
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest using Session instead:

```
Session["projectId"] = projectId;
```

```
var projectId = Session["projectId"];
```